# What are the Graph API use restrictions?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, restriction

I am working on a project that need to perform a lot of requests tou the Graph API. During my tests, I sometimes reach a limit in the Graph API use that seems to be one request per second.

As far as I will need more quota to make my project running, I would like to know which policy is currently in use to limit users' request flow? Is it limited by IP, by access_token? by user? Is there a way to get a bigger amount of requests per second? Is there a risk to be blacklisted?

I have searched on the official documentation, on many FAQ pages and on stackoverflow, but I have not been able to get an answer. Thanks for your help if you can help me on that critical point!

Answer (score 0):

Youre right, there's a limit of 600 reqs in 600 secs per access token. There should be very few valid use cases where you need exceed this limit. If you are, it's an indication that you're not doing something right.

However, the batch API and the realtime API can be used in valid cases to improve performance, and remove the need for you to have to poll the API.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer but I am still missing an information : am I limited for request without access_token? For example [nb likes](http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.kelblog.com/article-les-revenus-de-google-explosent-merci-panda-86516729.html). Actually, I would like to get/update this information for thousands of url each hour in order to add facebook datas in the news order algorithm of our home page (http://www.wikio.fr/). This algo aims to detect buzz news from more than 50 000 sources and as a result a big amount of news every days.

Comment: Facebook is not optimised for this use case. This is why you're hitting limits. You need to reduce the number of URLs your hitting, or reduce the frequency with which you hit them.